# "initializer list "vs. "default argument value" difference when setting a member value

Tags: c++, list, arguments, default, initializer

I've been experiencing a linking issue on a project, and I've found a workaround I can't really explain.

I had this kind of class and I was getting an unresolved external symbol on `getType<>()`, which was *correctly* imported from another lib.

```
MyClass( CustomType& iType = getType<OtherClass>() ) 
{...}
```

The workaround found is a little less reusable, but still satisfies conviniently my use case for now. Same linker properties, etc.

```
MyClass( ) 
: mType( getType<OtherClass>() ) 
{...}
```

- What difference does it make to set a member variable with a default argument value or through the initializer list?
- Is there a difference of scope? e.g. could it be because `otherClass` and `getType<>()` exist in different namespaces?

EDIT:
Declaration of getType:

```
template<typename type>
CustomType* getType() {
  static CustomType* oType = getType(typeid(type));
  return oType;
}
```

Linker error:

```
MyClass.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class CustomType * __thiscall Metadata::getType<class OtherClass>(void)" ...
```

Comment: You did implement `getType<>()` in the header?

Comment: @manni66 yes, in an included header

Comment: Show code, show the meaasge.

Comment: "CustomType& iType = getType..." is it a typo, or are you really binding a CustomType& to a CustomeType*  ? if yes, what's CustomType ?

Comment: `Metadata::` ??

Comment: `Metadata` is the namespace where `getType` is declared

Comment: there is no typo, this is actually how the code is

Comment: _there is no typo, this is actually how the code is_ that will **not** result in in linker error but in a copiler error. You do not show the relevant code. You are on your own.

Comment: alright, sorry for the disturbance. thank you both for your interest and have a good day

Comment: again, what's CustomType ? as of now, the only explanation I see is that CustomType has a non explicit constructor taking CustomType* and either CustomType is an alias for some const T or you're compiling with an old version of vc++ that allows binding lvalue references to rvalues ... either way, I don't see how this relates to the linker error though. Can you create an [mcve] ?

Comment: @Massimiliano I'll do that in a near future, it's really bugging me. Also this project does use an older compiler (VS2005)

Answer (score 0):

Default arguments are only "exectuted" at call site: so for

```
MyClass(CustomType& iType = getType<OtherClass>())
```

You only need declaration of `getType<OtherClass>()`.

Instantiation would be done only when you use something like:

```
MyClass myClass{}; // MyClass myClass{getType<OtherClass>()}
```

I assume that definition of `getType<OtherClass>` is inaccessible.
(you might have implementation of template inside cpp file)

For

```
MyClass() : mType(getType<OtherClass>()) {}
```

`getType<OtherClass>` is instantiated.

Comment: ... but the declaration should still be valid ( but this could be explained by a converting ctor and older vc++ allowing rvalue to lvalue reference binding, see comments ); moreover, if getType is not instantiated why the linker complains ? isn't there a contradiction here ?

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes: Does the code split in several projects ? is definition of `getType()` is in header ? That might explain the link error.